# Invalid hook call in NextJS without hooks

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So, I wanted to move from Vercel hosting to self-hosting (it always compiles there without a problem), but when I try to build it locally it throws the same error for every page:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/mapa". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at S (/home/monka/GithubTests/NextTest/nextjs-website/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:18:327)
    at Object.exports.useContext (/home/monka/GithubTests/NextTest/nextjs-website/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:22:269)
    at Html (/home/monka/GithubTests/NextTest/nextjs-website/.next/server/pages/_document.js:510:73)
    at d (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToStaticMarkup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:51:446)
    at renderToHTML (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:909:40)
    at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:275:36
```

The problem is that the code (as shown below) doesn't contain any hooks.

```
const Mapa = () => {

    return(
        <div>

            <iframe src="https://<website>/" className="mapa" title="mapa" scrolling="no" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Mapa;
```

Do you guys have any idea what might be causing this?
My node version is 17.4.0.

Comment: It could be your Node version. Latest Node versions may be insecure for production or development. Try downgrading to LTS version.

Comment: @ask4you I have tried with  16.14.0 LTS, but there's still the same error.

Comment: Have you done npm update inside proyect?

Comment: @ask4you I have removed both node_modules and .next folders and then used npm install, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Full reinstall of nodejs and npm fixed the issue!